# LLC.exe cannot produce assembly

Tags: windows, llvm, llvm-clang

I have a very simple C program called simple.c, and I want to use the LLVM toolchain to first produce IR Bitcode, then compile and link the bitcode myself.

This is what I currently do:

```
clang -O3 -emit-llvm simple.c -c -o simple.bc
llc -filetype=obj simple.bc <----  this is where it fails
```

simple.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

i can run the code when i compile it directly with clang, and i can run the bitcode with lli, however llc fails with this:

````
```C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet>llc -filetype=obj simple.bc
Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: llc -filetype=obj simple.bc
1.      Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module 'simple.bc'.
2.      Running pass 'Expand Atomic instructions' on function '@main'
 #0 0x0fa3aed0 (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll+0x8aed0)
 #1 0x0fa3d9ec (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll+0x8d9ec)
 #2 0x0fa3dfc0 (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll+0x8dfc0)
 #3 0x02800def (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x2430def)
 #4 0x029a3490 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x25d3490)
 #5 0x03f8b086 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x3bbb086)
 #6 0x03f8b279 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x3bbb279)
 #7 0x03f8ce06 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x3bbce06)
 #8 0x03f8dba8 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x3bbdba8)
 #9 0x00b84936 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x7b4936)
#10 0x00b7b056 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x7ab056)
#11 0x00b7b2d6 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x7ab2d6)
#12 0x00b78215 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x7a8215)
#13 0x00b84df6 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x7b4df6)
#14 0x00b86408 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x7b6408)
#15 0x01cc60d8 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x18f60d8)
#16 0x01cc4824 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x18f4824)
#17 0x01afa507 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x172a507)
#18 0x01a11eaf (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x1641eaf)
#19 0x01a0f0f6 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x163f0f6)
#20 0x02739ff3 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x2369ff3)
#21 0x02d448e2 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x29748e2)
#22 0x02d44bf4 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x2974bf4)
#23 0x02d45d52 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x2975d52)
#24 0x02d46595 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x2976595)
#25 0x02d3ff8d (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x296ff8d)
#26 0x006781a6 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x2a81a6)
#27 0x00678ed2 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x2a8ed2)
#28 0x044cde5e (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x40fde5e)
#29 0x044cdcf7 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x40fdcf7)
#30 0x044cdb8d (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x40fdb8d)
#31 0x044cded8 (C:\Users\Dvino\Desktop\hovet\hovet\llc.exe+0x40fded8)
#32 0x750f8494 (C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x18494)
#33 0x777f41c8 (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x641c8)
#34 0x777f4198 (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x64198)
```
````

Comment: What LLVM version are you using? How did you install it?

Comment: @arrowd I built the current version of LLVM from git https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project on Windows. Building exactly by documentation was successful and so were tests.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with just this version of LLC, I compiled and executed LLVM7, it worked just fine.